# BDE, Windows 7 and UAC

Tags: delphi, uac, delphi-5, bde

I have a very old application written in delphi 5 running in some customers which uses the BDE. Now some users with Windows Vista and 7, had experimented some problems with the multiuser access. i' think which these problems are related to the location of the `net`.and `.lck` files. so the question is which is the proper  way to confgure the `BDE` under Windows Vista and 7 to avoid permissions and UAC conflicts?

Comment: Tell us more about the problems that you are seeing. Also, have you manifested your app so that it isn't virtualized?

Comment: Once you've switched virtualization off you'll start getting errors when your app tries to write to folders which it doesn't have write access to.

Comment: Just so you're encouraged, we have several thousand workstations around the US running our D7/BDE app.  A big percentage of our users have migrated Windows 7, so there's no intrinsic problem that the answers below shouldn't resolve.  (Very rarely, on a development machine, I get a BDE memory sharing error.  The docs suggest, as I recall, setting a memory page in the BDEAdmin to "0BDE" (which I suspect is a somewhat "try something different" memory location chosen by Borland with no real significance. Rebooting takes care of the problem.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In addition to the above answer, you'll want to make sure that the .net and .lck files are located in a user-specific directory under Windows 7, specifically:

```
C:\Users\{User Name}\AppData\Local\{Your Company Name}\{Your Application Name}
```

Those are the only folders that the current user will always have complete control over.

You can get this folder by using this code:

```
CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA = $001C;

function GetAppDataDirectory: AnsiString;
var
   TempBuffer: array[0..MAX_PATH] of AnsiChar;
   ResultLength: Integer;
begin
   FillChar(TempBuffer,((MAX_PATH+1)*SizeOf(AnsiChar)),0);
   ShlObj.SHGetSpecialFolderPathA(0,@TempBuffer,CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA,False);
   ResultLength:=StrLen(pAnsiChar(@TempBuffer));
   SetLength(Result,ResultLength);
   Move(TempBuffer[0],pAnsiChar(Result)^,(ResultLength*SizeOf(AnsiChar)));
end;
```

and then appending `{Your Company Name}` and `{Your Application Name}` to the value returned.  You'll need to include the ShlObj unit.

Answer (score 4):

One such thing I remember is to configure the Session to put that kind of files on folders where a normal user have write-privileges.

From what I remember, the properties

```
Session.PrivateDir
Session.NetFileDir
```

Are the relevant ones.

The correct location will depend on concurrent access, the database you're connecting to, data location –in case of paradox or dbf's– and if you use cached updates or not.

I maintain an application written originally in D4, now compiled with D2007 when rarely needed and it works well on vista+ using this with it's particular configuration and needs (no paradox/dbf's).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to work around the security bugs in a default install of the BDE (as other answers mention - granting permissions that the BDE installer forgot to), you can just run your application as an **administrator**.

You have a few options:

1. Tell the user to right-click and select `Run As Administrator` every time.
2. Go to the program's Compatibility tab, and check `Run this program as an administrator` (which has the same effect as 1)
3. Go to the program's Compatibility tab, and `Run this program in compatibility mode` for `Windows XP` (which has the same effect as 2)
4. Create a manifest `MyApp.exe.manifest` and include the `requestedExecutionLevel` of `requireAdministrator` (which has the same effect as 3)

In other words: Your application, as it stands right now, requires administrative access to run - so just run it as an administrator.

On the other hand you can make a *few simple changes* and your application will *no longer* need to run as an administrator; you've made the world a better place for all humanity!