# Getting error while runnning the build exe on another machine

Tags: delphi

I  have createtd one application using Delphi 5 and BDE components. I have connected to database through ODBC connection. The application is running smoothly on my machine but its giving error while running the build exe on another machine. I have created the same ODBC connection on another machine also. but its giving error "An error Occurred while attempting to initialize Borland Database Engine". :( Any solution to this error? thanks for help. - Naren

Comment: Naren, you should really start by reading the documentation instead of adopting a trial&error approach. You will only waste a lot of time, and asking piece by piece you will only collect piece of informations instead of understanding the whole.

Comment: Is there any reason to stay with BDE? Although Delphi 5 is 12 years old, it includes the ADO based TDataSet derivatives (TADOQuery etc). A small project may be fairly easily updated to use ADO instead. Large projects will of course take longer. While Installing BDE on newer OSes isn't impossible, it isn't straight forward [either] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5384006/bde-windows-7-and-uac). It may be nearly impossible on yet to be released versions of Windows.

Comment: The main problem is I am using Delphi 5 professional version. Professional version does not include ADO components so i dont have any other option than using BDE.

Comment: @ldsandon: thanks for help. I am having very little time to complete the Utility so that i am asking these questions to u guys. That piece by piece information helping me to solve my problems. thanks again to all of u..

Answer (score 2):

Seems to me, that you haven't installed the BDE on the other machines you are trying to run your program. Without the BDE installed, running your program fails.

Comment: so it needs BDE installed on each machine where i want to run exe? If i want to run exe on 100 machines then each machine shoul have BDE? can we install only BDE?

Comment: Yes, you have to have BDE on every machine. Here are a few links: http://www.symantec.com/connect/downloads/bde-510-full-install http://cc.embarcadero.com/item/27573 http://www.jrsoftware.org/iskb.php?bde I Bet you will find more googling.

Comment: Yes. (this is overflowing with yes)

Comment: can u plz give me small idea. I tried to run the BDE exe on another machine but its giving error. thanks

Comment: Or can we install BDE on share and access the BDE from shared?

Comment: Have a look at the links in the second comment.

Comment: @Naren - what Windows version are you trying to install onto?

Comment: Assuming (from your comment about shares), another possibility would be to install once onto a terminal server, and have all users run the app on a single machine. As it's Delphi 5 we don't have to worry about Windows XP+ themes.

Comment: install once on terminal server and can all users acces that app without installing BDE on thier machine?

Comment: @Naren: terminal server is "free" only for administrative purposes and two users. Otherwise you have to pay CALs (client access licenses) for each user accessing it. It's cheaper to install the BDE. Because the BDE is made of several DLLs and some initial settings, you should use a setup program to deploy it. There is a merge module for Windows Installer based setups, while Inno Setup site has informations on how to deploy the BDE using it. It should deployed properly to work without issues (http://www.jrsoftware.org/iskb.php?bde)